# Graphics3D plot of group of Vectors

Tags: graphics, dynamic, vector

I am trying to overlap 2 different Coordinate Systems (C1,C2).

I want it to be visually pleasing but it is increasing the length of code

I tried

```
dc1={{1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1}};
origin1={0,0,0};
dc2={{1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2], 0},{-1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2], 0},{0,0,1}};
origin2={1,1,0};
data1=(origin1+#&)/@dc1;
data2=(origin2+#&)/@dc2;
a=Graphics3D[{Red,Arrow[{origin1, #}]&/@data1}, Axes -> True, Boxed -> True];
b=Graphics3D[{Blue,Arrow[{origin2, #}]&/@data2}, Axes -> True, Boxed -> True];
Show[a,b]
```

[image: Output]

How to code it in effective manner?

*How to label each axis of C1(red) and C2(blue)*

*Suggestions on making `dc1` `dc2` `origin1` `orgin2` inputs dynamic would be helpul .. similar to `Manipulate` function *

Answer (score 1):

I don't consider the following terribly complicated, but you might hopefully pick something up from this:

```
Graphics3D[{{Red, 
             MapThread[{Text[Style[#2, Large, Bold], #1, {0, -1}], 
                        Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, #1}]]} &,
                       {IdentityMatrix[3], {"x", "y", "z"}}]}, 
            With[{tr = Composition[TranslationTransform[{1, 1, 0}], 
                                   RotationTransform[π/4, {0, 0, 1}]]},
            {Blue, 
             MapThread[{Text[Style[#2, Large, Bold], tr @ #1, {0, -1}], 
                        Arrow[Tube[tr @ {{0, 0, 0}, #1}]]} &,
                       {IdentityMatrix[3], {"x'", "y'", "z'"}}]}]}, Axes -> True]
```

[image: two coordinate systems]